# How to simplify sum with a binomial

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

I am stuck on this problem:

Simplify the sum $$
\sum_{k=0}^n {n+k \choose k} 2^{-k}.
$$

I multiplied it by $\frac{2^n}{2^n}$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n {n+k \choose k} 2^{n-k} = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n {n+k \choose n} 2^{n-k}
$$
How should I proceed? I tried to use the formula $\sum_{i=r}^n {i \choose r} =  {n+1 \choose r+1}$ but I don't know how to aply it here.

Comment: Hint: Use generating functions.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function) on Wiki, there is a more general problem and answer.